# Does a 300W Transformer use 300W when a 12W appliance is connected?

Tags: transformer

I've been wondering: if you connect a 12W device to a 300W step-up transformer, how much power is consumed?  Does it use the whole 300W the entire time, regardless of what's connected, or is it an upper-bound?

I'm also keen to learn *why*.

Comment: A slightly more than 12W is consumed; 300W is an upper-bound. Your last question is hard to answer because it happens to be a fundamental rule in this universe;-)

Comment: The power dissipated in an idling 300W transformer could be up to 5% of its rated power, so it may take 10-15W in addition to the 12W load. This power goes to magnetising a relatively large core. So it's likely to be about 50% efficient overall, where a transformer rated for 12W may be 80-90% efficient driving the same load.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A basic rule for transformers is: Power in = power out plus losses.

With no load, your transformer will take a few watts, just keeping the core magnetized and wasting a bit as heat due to resistance in the primary winding.

With a small load, such as your 12 watts, the transformer power input will be that 12 watts, plus the few watts it would consume without a load, and a bit more, due to increased current.

The 300 watts is the maximum recommended load - exceeding that will overheat the transformer, and may cause some damage (beware if you smell burning transformer varnish!)